# Javascript date.getDay() inconsistency

Tags: javascript, date

I think I have found an issue in Javascript's date.getDay() function. This week, my 'day-of-the-week' (mon,tues, etc) started to be off by one in one of my applications. I have dug in further and have been able to isolate the date(s) when the date broke. I understand that getDay() returns `[0-6]` corresponding to `[sun-sat]`. However, it is returning 5 for both `March 31, 2015` and `April 1, 2015`. Anyone have any insight as to why? My date object looks like both:

```
var date = new Date('2015','02','31');
```

and

```
var date = new Date('2015','03','01');
```

The alert you see is

```
alert(date.getDay());
```

See screenshots below for example
[image]
[image]

EDIT: See [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8pvecLo5/)

Comment: hi can you put your code in jsfiddle?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/8pvecLo5/

Comment: @AlexNeigher you said in my answer you are aware of the months starting by 0, but in your fiddle your are starting by 1 ;) Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8pvecLo5/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The month is expressed by numbers from 0-11.

From https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

month
Integer value representing the month, beginning with 0 for January to 11 for December.

The error appears because  the initializing of the date-object is wrong - its initialized like that: new Date('2015','04','01');, which is the first of may, and new Date('2015','03','31'); which is the 31st of april, a day that doesnt exist, so JS does the best of it and takes the day after the 30th of april, 1st of may

Comment: I am aware that both month and day are 0 indexed arrays, regardless of the initialization, why would it return the same value?

Comment: He's asking about getDay()--nothing to do with months

Comment: @AlexNeigher because the initializing of the date-object is wrong - its initialized like that: new Date('2015','04','01');, which is the first of may, and new Date('2015','03','31'); which is the 31st of april, a day that doesnt exist, so JS does the best of it and takes the day after the 30th  april, 1st of may.

Comment: @dave i guess he's date is incorrect because month 02 is not month 2 but  3 and its really friday 5

Comment: @JohannesReuter, Your answer is correct. If you want to answer the question with that, I will mark it as the correct answer. Thank you for the insight...

Comment: @AlexNeigher from my perspective the answer is fine like that, you can approve it